# how do I set a circle in an rgb image to black having the centre and radius in hand?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have already tried checking `if (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 <= r^2` , however when i set `img(x,y)=0;` the circle becomes an opaque blue color. I actually want it black. Please help as I am pretty new to Matlab.

Comment: please add the details what you have tried.

Comment: I just tried out the answer suggested by @Jacob and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `img(x,y,:) = 0` since RGB images have 3 channels (R,G,B) and are stored as 3D matrices. The `:` command will set all 3 values corresponding to the `x,y` pixel to `0`.